How can I draw a portion of a TMetafile to a TCanvas?
For reasons, I store EMF and BMP images in TMetafiles. When I export these graphics to PDF with 300 DPI, some pictures disappear from the output.
The solution : I have to cut the pictures into parts. It is an easy thing with TBitmaps because they have a Canvas. I have a problem with TMetafile as it has no Canvas (TMetafileCanvas is just a surface to modify the metafile contents, not for representing it).
I divide the output size maximized to 3000 px in both directions. I have to iterate the parts. But how can I draw a portion of a TMetafile (defined by rc : TRect) to a TCanvas (with the same sizes as the rc)?
I tried the cutting regions, but how could I convert the left-top coords into (0;0) in the output TCanvas?
Should I use somehow the setWorldTransform Win API call? Please help me!

Does https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15544766/metafile-clipping-rectangle answer your question?

@TomBrunberg
Ooooooh!  If I pass negative translation coords to the Canvas.draw, I get the right content! Yes, it answered the missing part of my question! Thx!

OK, I closed this question as a duplicate. You may want to (if you wish) upvote the linked answer that helped you.
